# How to refer to rich edit control in another class

Tags: mfc, text-editor, cricheditctrl

I have a simple MFC text editor and I am trying to implement a find function. I'm trying to refer to the control that stores all the text(I believe this is in the View class) from my 'Find Box' Dialog class. How do i access this rich edit control when it is in another class?

Comment: Your question is sorely lacking in information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of the Find dialog to receive an additional parameter: a pointer to the rich edit control. Save the pointer in a Find dialog member variable. Then pass in the pointer value when you construct the Find dialog.